# CSS parent same width as child object?

Tags: css

While creating a informal dropdown (something like a , but then with images) within a bunch of text, the parent width (the normally visible text) isn't set correctly according the width of the dropdown. I'd want the dropdown to be the definition of the width of the clickable item.

The width of the green (#st) is displayed perfectly without the 'display: block;' on the #nd, but then the #nd isn't overflowing the text around it.

I've been debugging it's behavior for the past 2 days with Firefox Developer Tools (prev known as FireBug), but didn't find any usable solution. It's been ~5 years ago when I've touched CSS for the last time. Used to be capable of doing this without any headache. ;-)

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#st {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

#nd {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfasd asdaff</li>
  <li>tgestergsgfsdfg
    <div id="container">
      <span id="st">testing</span>
      <ul id="nd">
        <li>sadfasdf asdfsadf</li>
        <li>rwert2345234 345345</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see any dropdown menu, is there one you can share? It's not possible to tell what you want to do from that red and green random text block.

Comment: The green part is the dropdown, the red part is which is normally visible. The red part should have the same width as the green (dropdown) part. It's just an simplification of the problem without any effects (:hover/whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Giving `position:absolute` to an element causes it to be removed from the document flow. That allows it to sit in a layer above (or below, in some cases) other elements, but even it's direct parent element can't tell its dimensions or position.

Sometimes you can use this as an alternative to giving an element `position:absolute`

```
float: left;
margin-bottom: -999em;
position: relative;
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#st {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

#nd {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -999em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfasd asdaff</li>
  <li>tgestergsgfsdfg
    <div id="container">
      <span id="st">testing</span>
      <ul id="nd">
        <li>sadfasdf asdfsadf</li>
        <li>rwert2345234 345345</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
  <li>sadfasdf asdf sadfasdf asdfas dfasdfas dfasdfas</li>
</ul>
```